# JSF- <f:ajax> can't render datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have a datatable which has a `"delete"` button at each row,
and I want to re-render the table when the data at the row is deleted.

But I can not make `f:ajax` work properly.

Here is the datatable at facelet page:

```
<h:form>
 <h:dataTable  value="#{adminPanelBean.activitiesList}" var="activityItem" id="allActivities"
                          styleClass="datatable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4"
                          columnClasses="ColName,colType,colTime,colPlace,colSummary" >
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Etkinlik"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{activityItem.name}  "/>

                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Türü"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{activityItem.type}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Tarih "/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{activityItem.time}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Yer "/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{activityItem.place}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Açıklama "/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{activityItem.summary}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
                    </f:facet>
            **<h:commandButton  value="Delete activity" onclick="if(confirm(' Delete #{activityItem.name} ?'))return true; else return false;"  action="#{adminPanelBean.deleteActivity(activityItem.id)}">&nbsp;
                    <f:ajax event="click" render="allActivities" execute="@all" immediate="true"/>
            <f:param name="activityId" value ="#{activityItem.id}"  />
               </h:commandButton>**
             </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

When I refresh the page, I see the row is deleted. But I want it to be done dynamically.

Comment: I solved changing the render to @form `<f:ajax render="@form" .../>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the action method you need to remove the item from the list as well (and thus not only from the DB). I'd suggest to pass the whole item instead of only the ID so that you can utilize `List#remove()` method.

```
action="#{adminPanelBean.deleteActivity(activityItem)}">
```

So that you can do

```
public void deleteActivity(Activity activity) {
    activitiesList.remove(activity);
    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, they way how you used `confirm()` is pretty clumsy.

```
onclick="if(confirm(' Delete #{activityItem.name} ?'))return true; else return false;"
```

That function returns a `boolean` already. You do not need to test the obtained boolean within an `if` in order to return another `boolean`. Just simplify it as follows:

```
onclick="return confirm('Delete #{activityItem.name}?')"
```

Comment: Well i didn't think removing the row item from the list first, i was removing it at db and getting all items from db to list again... 

But i tried your solution and it worked, thanks! (and thanks for js help too.)