# Changing rich faces extendeddatatable height from a command button Click

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, richfaces, facelets

I am new to RichFaces and Facelets. I am trying to increase the height of an ExtendedDataTable defined in my project. I have a command button in the xhtml called "Expand". When I click on "Expand" I want the height of the Extended Data Table to change (say for example from 200px to 700px). Is this possible? If so how can it be done? Suggestions would be appreciated!!

I am using richfaces-3.3.3.

Here is the Facelets page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
<title>RichFaces</title>
</head>
<body>
<rich:panel id="searchResultsPanel" header="Search Results Panel" bodyClass="no-padding">
<table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><rich:extendedDataTable var="result" enableContextMenu="true" height="200px" width="935px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="partsSearchResultsTable" rows="4" selectionMode="none">
<rich:column sortable="false" width="50">
<f:facet name="header">
Source
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="TestColumn1" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortable="false" width="125">
<f:facet name="header">
Part Number
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="TestColumn2" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortable="false" width="225">
<f:facet name="header">
Part Description
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="TestColumn3" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortable="false" width="100">
<f:facet name="header">
HTS
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="TestColumn4" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortable="false" width="65">
<f:facet name="header">
Priority
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="TestColumn5" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortable="false" width="65" style="text-align: center;">
<f:facet name="header">
Flags
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="TestColumn6" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortable="false" width="65">
<f:facet name="header">
Status
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="TestColumn7" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortable="false" width="95">
<f:facet name="header">
Update Date
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="TestColumn8" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column sortable="false" width="75">
<f:facet name="header">
User  Id
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="TestColumn9" />
</rich:column>
<rich:datascroller id="datascroller" for="partsSearchResultsTable" selectedStyle="font-weight:bold" />
</rich:extendedDataTable></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><h:panelGroup id="resultListButtonGroup">
<a4j:commandButton value="Remove" styleClass="button" />
<h:commandButton id="archiveOrActivateBtn" value="Archive" styleClass="button" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" />
<h:commandButton id="psExportBtn" value="Export Selected" styleClass="long-btn" />
<h:commandButton id="psExportXnumBtn" value="Export 15,000" styleClass="long-btn" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
<a4j:commandButton value="Expand" styleClass="button" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
</h:panelGroup></td>
</tr>
</table>
</rich:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply keep the height in a variable, then update it and rerender the table.

It can also be done through JavaScript, like this:

```
<h:outputScript>
    expandTable = function (height) {
        var edt = #{rich:component('table')},
            div = edt.mainDiv,
            body = edt.scrollingTable,
            divHeight = div.getHeight() + height,
            bodyHeight = body.getHeight() + height;

            table.setHeight(tableHeight);
            body.setHeight(bodyHeight);
        }        
</h:outputScript>
```

But this may not always work (i.e. some features of the datable may still work with the old values).

Comment: Makhiel, the h:outputScript should be defined as an external Java script? Also, can you please guide me on how I can define the height variable and rerender the extendeddatatable?

Comment: You can put the `outputScript` on the page, or its contents in an external file, it doesn't matter. The variable will be defined in a bean, then you'll just access it like any other, i.e. `height="#{bean.tableHeight}"`. You make the `a4j:commandButton` change the value (`action="#{bean.changeHeight()}"`) and then use `reRender="partsSearchResultsTable"` so that the table is updated.

Comment: I am trying this by specifying the height in the Bean and changing it using a method. But I have been getting this error: Message: Object required
Line: 201
Char: 440
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/richfaces-start/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript.jsf. Not sure if this is to do with my syntax or if I am committing any obvious mistake. Any suggestions? I can post the Bean and the modified Facelet in my Answer section below.

Answer (score 0):

The Bean for this facelet:

```
package com.richfacesstart.example;
```

public class ResultListBean {

```
String height;

public ResultListBean() {
    super();
    height = "200px";
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public void changeHeight() {
    setHeight("700px");
}
```

}

The Modified Facelet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
<title>RichFaces</title>
</head>
<body>
    <rich:panel id="searchResultsPanel" header="Search Results Panel"
        bodyClass="no-padding">
        <table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><rich:extendedDataTable var="result"
                        enableContextMenu="true" height="#{ResultListBean.height}"
                        width="935px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                        id="partsSearchResultsTable" rows="4" selectionMode="none">
                        <rich:column sortable="false" width="50">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            Source
                        </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="TestColumn1" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column sortable="false" width="125">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            Part Number
                        </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="TestColumn2" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column sortable="false" width="225">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            Part Description
                        </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="TestColumn3" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column sortable="false" width="100">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            HTS
                        </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="TestColumn4" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column sortable="false" width="65">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            Priority
                        </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="TestColumn5" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column sortable="false" width="65"
                            style="text-align: center;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            Flags
                        </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="TestColumn6" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column sortable="false" width="65">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            Status
                        </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="TestColumn7" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column sortable="false" width="95">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            Update Date
                        </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="TestColumn8" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column sortable="false" width="75">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                            User  Id
                        </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="TestColumn9" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:datascroller id="datascroller" for="partsSearchResultsTable"
                            selectedStyle="font-weight:bold" />
                    </rich:extendedDataTable></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><h:panelGroup id="resultListButtonGroup">
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Remove" styleClass="button" />
                        <h:commandButton id="archiveOrActivateBtn" value="Archive"
                            styleClass="button"
                            style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" />
                        <h:commandButton id="psExportBtn" value="Export Selected"
                            styleClass="long-btn" />
                        <h:commandButton id="psExportXnumBtn" value="Export 15,000"
                            styleClass="long-btn" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Expand" styleClass="button"
                            style="margin-left: 10px;"
                            action="#{ResultListBean.changeHeight}"
                            reRender="partsSearchResultsTable" />
                    </h:panelGroup></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </rich:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

My faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="1.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">
 <application>
  <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
 </application> 

   <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>ResultListBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.richfacesstart.example.ResultListBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Makhiel .. thanks a lot for your suggestion!! I was trying to debug what caused the A4J script related error i had stated above... It turned out to be because the extended data table re-rendering was failing. After searching a bit, came across this answer: [Datatable not rendering with ajax call in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213031/datatable-not-rendering-with-ajax-call-in-jsf)

which had a similar issue. I enclosed the Rich Panel and components in a  and bam!! it worked!!

Thanks a lot for your suggestion.. it really helped me understand a bit of this rich faces and facelets!!

Comment: If you're just starting with JSF and RichFaces you should consider using the newer versions, RF 3 is fairly outdated.